# Float text under a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi I've got this code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.myText {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myText">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

My goal is, that the text within the yellow box floats under the orange one (if it is too long like in the example. Something like this:

[image]

I have no ideas how to do this and I didn't found any solutions on the internet. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It's easily possible it you put orange box **into** yellow one. Is it a problem?

Comment: Change in order of text `.myText` and `.box` possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.myText {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: justify;
}
.box {
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
  height: 60px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="myText">
    <div class="box"></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it works and it's still with flexbox - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try placing `.box` at top and `float: right;`.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: justify;
}
.myText {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="myText">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, is there also a way with flexbox?

Comment: Wait. I'll try it.

Comment: Hi again, there is a solution with flexbox and I marked it as correct. You can look at it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I hope, there is no need to use flex.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of is you put orange box inside yellow one and before writing any text. Something like this

```
<div class="myText">
  <div class="box"></div>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
```

You also have to make change in your CSS. Add this one property with box class.

```
float:right;
```